# Git - new commits in merged branch -- how to merge these new commits?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a following issue:
I merged a branch `test` into `master`, after that my collegue pushed two commits into `test`.
I would like to again merge these two commits  to `master`, but I wouldn't like to use `cherry-pick`.

What should I do?

Comment: Just merge again?

Comment: `git fetch origin test:test` to update your local `test`. `git checkout master` to make sure you are on `master`. `git merge test` again to merge the new commits. If after your first merge, you haven't made new commits or applied any other commits yet, you could run `git fetch origin test:test;git checkout master;git reset HEAD^ --hard;git merge test` so that the history looks better.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

Method 1:

Switch to master branch and pull test branch

```
git checkout master
git pull origin test (it performs merge test branch to master branch)
```

Method 2:

1. Switch to test branch and pull new commits

   git pull origin test
2. Switch to master branch and merge test branch to master.

   git merge test